# Assignment within RAII scope

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, raii

#### Problem

How do you initialize an object inside a RAII scope, and use it outside of that scope?

#### Background

- I have a global lock which can be called with `lock()` and `unlock()`.
- I have a type, `LockedObject`, which can only be initialized when the global lock is locked.
- I have a function, `use_locked(LockedObject &locked_object)`, which needs to be called with the global lock unlocked.

The usage scenario is

```
lock();
LockedObject locked_object;
unlock();
use_locked(locked_object);
```

#### RAII

For various reasons, I moved to a RAII encapsulation of the global lock. I would like to use this everywhere, primarily as creating `LockedObject` can fail with exceptions.

The problem is that

```
{
    GlobalLock global_lock;
    LockedObject locked_object;
}
use_locked(locked_object);
```

fails, as `locked_object` is created in the inner scope.

#### Examples

Set-up (mostly not important):

```
#include <assert.h> 
#include <iostream>

bool locked = false;

void lock() {
    assert(!locked);
    locked = true;  
}

void unlock() {
    assert(locked);
    locked = false;
}

class LockedObject {
    public:
        LockedObject(int i) {
            assert(locked);
            std::cout << "Initialized: " << i << std::endl;
        }
};

void use_locked(LockedObject locked_object) {
    assert(!locked);
}

class GlobalLock {
    public:
        GlobalLock() {
            lock();
        }

        ~GlobalLock() {
            unlock();
        }
};
```

Original, non RAII method:

```
void manual() {
    lock();
    LockedObject locked_object(123);
    unlock();
    use_locked(locked_object);
}
```

Broken RAII methods:

```
/*
void raii_broken_scoping() {
    {
        GlobalLock global_lock;

        // Initialized in the wrong scope
        LockedObject locked_object(123);
    }
    use_locked(locked_object);
}
*/

/*
void raii_broken_initialization() {
    // No empty initialization
    // Alternatively, empty initialization requires lock
    LockedObject locked_object;
    {
        GlobalLock global_lock;
        locked_object = LockedObject(123);
    }
    use_locked(locked_object);
}
*/
```

And a `main` function:

```
int main(int, char **) {
    manual();
    // raii_broken_scoping();
    // raii_broken_initialization;
}
```

---

For what it's worth, in Python I would do:

```
with GlobalLock():
    locked_object = LockedObject(123)
```

I want the equivalent of that. I mention my current solution in an answer, but it feels clumsy.

---

The specific (but simplified) code to be executed follows. With my current lambda-based call:

```
boost::python::api::object wrapped_object = [&c_object] () {
    GIL lock_gil;
    return boost::python::api::object(boost::ref(c_object));
} ();

auto thread = std::thread(use_wrapped_object, c_object);
```

with

```
class GIL {
    public:
        GIL();
        ~GIL();

    private:
        GIL(const GIL&);
        PyGILState_STATE gilstate;
};
```

```
GIL::GIL() {
    gilstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
}

GIL::~GIL() {
    PyGILState_Release(gilstate);
}
```

`boost::python::api::object`s *must* be created with the GIL and the thread *must* be created without the GIL. The `PyGILState` struct and function calls are all given to me by CPython's C API, so I can only wrap them.

Comment: Not addressing your question but concurrency and sync'ing in general: There's plenty of support for that in C++11's <thread> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread.

Comment: @Solkar The specifics here are actually referencing Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) for an embedded Python interpreter. But thanks for the link.

Comment: I tend to avoid naked globals and host them in a singleton. Have you considered using a singleton?

Comment: @Solkar The global was just there to make the example shorter; I'm not actually implementing the lock like that.

Comment: I see. But pls note that we may miss the best solution for you, if the framework is not known. E.g. a singleton factory could provide better means to manage that than we ever would discuss here.

Comment: @Solkar I've given an example that involves the actual locking functions involved.

Comment: To have a RAII object to acquire a lock and securing an unlock at the destruction point (in case of exception for example) does not means you cannot add an anticipated unlock `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock`.

Comment: @galop1n It's a good proposal and would work quite well, but *in my specific case* I would unfortunately have to make the RAII scope larger than it should be in order to allow access to the `std::thread`. That effectively just delays the problem. I'll keep it in mind, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate your object on the heap and use some pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<LockedObject> locked_object;
{
    GlobalLock global_lock;
    locked_object.reset(new LockedObject());
}
use_locked(locked_object);
```

Comment: +1 Yup. If scope exit would destroy more stack than you'd want it to, you allocate on the heap.

Comment: I later ended up pretty much having to use this. My guess is that in most cases where you have lifetime concerns that the stack isn't helping with, it's best just making the leap then instead of trying to work around it as I originally did.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete list of options from my perspective.  `optional` would be what I would do:

The proposed post-C++1y `optional` would solve your problem, as it lets you construct data after declaration, as would heap based `unique_ptr` solutions.  Roll your own, or steal ot from `boost`

A 'run at end of scope' RAII function storer (with 'commit') can also make this code less crazy, as can letting your locks be manually disengaged within their scope.

```
template<class F>
struct run_at_end_of_scope {
  F f;
  bool Skip;
  void commit(){ if (!Skip) f(); Skip = true; }
  void skip() { Skip = true; }
  ~run_at_end_of_scope(){commit();}
};
template<class F>
run_at_end_of_scope<F> at_end(F&&f){ return {std::forward<F>(f), false}; }
```

then:

```
auto later = at_end([&]{ /*code*/ });
```

and you can `later.commit();` or `later.skip();` to run the code earlier or skip running it.

Making your RAII locking classes have move constructors would let you do construction in another scope, and return via move (possibly elided).

```
LockedObject make_LockedObject(){
  GlobalLock lock;
  return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use an anonymous function:

```
void raii_return() {
    LockedObject locked_object = [&] () {
        GlobalLock global_lock;
        return LockedObject(123);
    } ();
    use_locked(locked_object);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it avoids pointers and thanks to [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) it should be quite fast.

One downside is that `LockedObject`s don't necessarily support copying (`use_locked` would in that case take a reference).